# ImportError: No module named comments.models

Tags: python, django

I'm getting errors when using the new `django_comments` which [replaced](http://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting.html) `django.contrib.comments`. Any ideas on how to get around this error?

I'm installing the comment app [django-threadedcomments](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments) on [django-fluent-comments](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-comments) - which is fully supported.

```
File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/threadedcomments/models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
ImportError: No module named comments.models
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ## comments apps start
    'threadedcomments',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_comments',
    'fluent_comments',
    'crispy_forms',
    ## comments apps end
)
```

Comment: Try using the latest development version of django_comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I think you missed this:

```
pip install django-contrib-comments
```

and use latest code

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment # old
from django_comments.models import Comment # new
```