# ImportError: No module named comments django

Tags: django

I'm using os x , I tried to run the project that I installed from Github
https://github.com/cfpb/idea-box

but there is error says : ImportError: No module named comments

maybe I miss something but since I'm newbie in Django I can't figure it out

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your actual question, particularly your installed apps in your settings.py file. It would also be a good idea to include what you have tried/researched and why that hasn't helped solve your problem thus far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django comments are deprecated in latest version. You can either install older django version (such as 1.5).
Or the better solution is to install comments from external repository like so:

```
pip install django-contrib-comments
```

and then change all imports like this:

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment # old
from django_comments.models import Comment # new
```

Sources:

[Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/comments/)

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160282/importerror-no-module-named-comments-models)

Comment: thank you Ritave it works , but i got another issue says AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet"

Comment: That's a bigger problem that may stem from many places in the idea-box package, and would require longer debugging. I don't think SO is the best place for solving that - report an issue on project's github perhaps?
I assume you resolved the import problems, not downgraded Django - I guess that may be the only option left for you right know: either don't use the package or use Django 1.5.4.
(Imho the idea-box is a dead project, I would find another package)

Comment: thank you for your support , i interested on idea-box implementation and i also submit an issue on github , yeah i think so since there is no update ;(